# how can I swap two child entity values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity called "Space" and inside it has "Images". Images has an ordering property that is an int. I'm trying to see if there is an easy linq that can be made to swap the ordering values.

```
public class Space
{
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SpaceImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public class SpaceImage
{
    public int SpaceImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }
}
```

ex. 
an image might have ordering 3 and another will have 6, I want to swap these two numbers for each of these images

```
public void Swap(int spaceId, int old, int new)
{
    //swap 3 and 6 for the ordering value for the two spaceImages that contain these values where spaceId is spaceId
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing in the `SpaceImageId` you wish to swap the order for?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm accessing the image data through the 'Space' entity.

Comment: If so, there's no need for `spaceId` then, since it's part of the entity already.

Comment: I think I do need spaceId. Space and SpaceImage have a one-to-many relationship. So I want to swap the image ordering for images related to a specific space id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, LINQ would be used for querying.  You could use it to find the appropriate `SpaceImage` instances, then set the values appropriately:

```
// Assuming this is a method in the Space class
public void Swap(int oldOrder, int newOrder)
{
    var oldInst = this.Images.FirstOrDefault(si => si.Ordering == oldOrder);
    var newInst = this.Images.FirstOrDefault(si => si.Ordering == newOrder);

    if (oldInst != null && newInst != null)
    {
        oldInst.Ordering = newOrder;
        newInst.Ordering = oldOrder;
    }
    else
    {
        // There weren't matching images - handle that case here
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I save these back through my "Space" repository? I don't have a image repo just one for "Space"

Comment: @user1186050 Well, this is on the entity.  This sets the properties on those objects, so save however you save normally.

Comment: right now I only have a spacerepo.insertorupdate(space) call that I can make. If I set these two images back in the space and then pass the space to the repo will that save the image data that has been updated?

Comment: @user1186050 Depends on the repo, but typically, yes.